# Test belongs_to included by concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, activesupport-concern

I have a model

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Respondable
end
```

in DB **surveys** table have next fields:

- responses_saved_date
- responses_saved_by_type
- responses_saved_by_id

and module

```
module Respondable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :responses_saved_by,    :polymorphic => :true
  end

  def update_saved_settings!(person=nil)
    self.responses_saved_date = Time.now
    self.responses_saved_by   = person
    self.save
  end
end
```

I try to write unit tests for Respondable concern, to test it in isolation, according to this blogpost https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-mixins-in-isolation-with-minitest-and-rspec

Here is my rspec:

```
describe Respondable do
  class DummySurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Respondable
  end

  subject { DummySurvey.new }

  it { should belong_to(:responses_saved_by) }

  it 'saves the settings with user' do
    subject.update_saved_settings!(user)

    subject.responses_saved_date.should_not be_nil
    subject.responses_saved_by.should eq user
  end

  it 'saves the settings without user' do
    subject.update_saved_settings!

    subject.responses_saved_date.should_not be_nil
    subject.responses_saved_by.should be_nil
  end
end
```

When I run tests I receive next Error:

```
Failure/Error: subject { DummySurvey.new }
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
    PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "dummy_survey" does not exist
    LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"dummy_survey"'...
                                 ^
    : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                         pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                      ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                   WHERE a.attrelid = '"dummy_survey"'::regclass
                     AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                   ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you write

```
class DummySurvey < Survey
```

instead of

```
class DummySurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
```

you should be golden. When you define a class inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` there's an expectation that your database has the correct tables and columns (set up via migrations, and determined by Rails naming conventions).

Rails should reset the test database after test runs, so using the same model class as your actual app is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some way to test it in isolation would be:

```
describe Respondable do
  class DummySurvey
    attr_accessor :responses_saved_date, :responses_saved_by
    def save
      @saved = true
    end

    def persisted?
      @saved
    end

    def self.belongs_to(association, options = {})
      @associations ||= {}
      @associations[association] = OpenStruct.new(active_record: true, macro: :belongs_to,
        options: options, foreign_key: options[:foreign_key] || "#{association}_id")
    end

    def self.reflect_on_association(association)
      @associations ||= {}
      @associations[association]
    end

    def self.column_names
      ['responses_saved_by_type', 'responses_saved_by_id']
    end

    include Respondable
  end

  subject { DummySurvey.new }
  let(:user) { Object.new }

  it { should belong_to(:responses_saved_by) }

  it 'saves the settings with user' do
    subject.update_saved_settings!(user)

    subject.responses_saved_date.should_not be_nil
    subject.responses_saved_by.should eq user
    subject.should be_persisted
  end

  it 'saves the settings without user' do
    subject.update_saved_settings!

    subject.responses_saved_date.should_not be_nil
    subject.responses_saved_by.should be_nil
    subject.should be_persisted
  end
end
```

Alternatively you can create database table for class `DummySurvey` in tests or set `table_name` of existent table:

```
class DummySurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'surveys'
  include Respondable
end
```